# C# - Trying to create a singleton class

Tags: c#, singleton

I've been reading about how to implement a **thread safe** singleton class. I've managed to find many different ways of creating one, however I have not managed to find information about where exactly I'm supposed to put my properties and methods etc. in the class.

For example:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
   //Do I put properties here?     

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton GetInstance()
   {
      return NestedSingleton.singleton;
   }

   class NestedSingleton
   {
      //Do I put properties here?  
      internal static readonly Singleton singleton = new Singleton();

      static NestedSingleton() {}

      //Do my methods go here
   }

  //or here?
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The methods would go in the outer class. The *only* purpose of the nested class is to enforce particular timing of the initialization of the singleton instance of the outer class.

Don't forget that your `GetInstance` method returns a reference to `Singleton` - not `NestedSingleton`. Indeed, `NestedSingleton` is private, so code outside `Singleton` doesn't even know about its existence. You might want to make it a `static` class, too. (That would stop you from even *trying* to add instance members to it.)

Personally I would only use this form if I wanted *really* tight control over initialization - normally I'd just use a field in the `Singleton` class itself. (Or a `Lazy<T>`...) That's a bit simpler. If you haven't already come across my [article on singleton implementations in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx), you might want to have a look at it. (I suspect you've already seen it, but...)

Answer (score 3):

You should put all instance members in the outer class.

The inner class is a private holder type which only exists to lazily initialize the singleton value.
It should be `static`.

Comment: So I should have "static class NestedSingleton"?

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [this post](http://forums.asp.net/post/4390617.aspx) , this is the Singleton implementation I use in some of my projects.

In C# < 4, you can use :

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton _instance;
    private static object _lock = new object();

    private Singleton(){}

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null)
            {
               lock(_lock)
               {
                   if(_instance == null)
                       _instance = new Singleton();
               }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Or in C# 4

```
public class Singleton
{
     private Singleton(){}
     private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> _instance = new Lazy<Singleton>(()=>new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance{ get {return _instance.Value; } }
}
```

This implementation is thread safe.